# Why my string parameter is different when called in c++ import method

Tags: c#, visual-c++, pinvoke

I'm using C++ method in my C# code, everything works fine except one method

I've printed the value of the parameter in my c++ code and he is different from what i'm using in my C# code

That's the method i'm invoking in my C# code

```c
__declspec(dllexport) unsigned int _stdcall FindPattern(const char* signature, const char* mask)
{
    return Networking::instance()->findPattern(signature, mask);
}
```

Import

```cs
[DllImport("NtCore.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]
internal static extern uint FindPattern(string signature, string mask);
```

Call

```cs
uint address = _session.FindPattern("\x3B\x43\x00\x75\x0E\x8B\x44\xBB\x08", "xx?xxxxxx");
```

The signature parameters is equals to ";C" instead of "\x3B\x43\x00\x75\x0E\x8B\x44\xBB\x08"

Comment: A C-string cannot contain an embedded 0, since 0 is used to determine the string length.  It is 2.  So it is not actually a string, you could only get ahead by using byte[] in the C# code.  With the additional burden that the C code must explicitly pass the length of the array.

Answer (score 2):

`"\x3B\x43\x00"` is actually a series of bytes that are equivalent to `";C"`. `0x3b` is the semicolon, `0x43` is upper-case `C`, and `0x00` is a NUL terminator.

If you want the *literal* string, you should escape the `\` characters with something like:

```
"\\x3B\\x43\\x00\\x75\\x0E\\x8B\\x44\\xBB\\x08"
```